# Batch updates reporting contention error using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update in a collection and there are 1400+ offices are there and after checking and running the query I am updating in a collection document and update in the subcollection with few details after querying but sometimes i am getting this error
10 ABORTED: Too much contention on these documents. Please try again.
and i am simply using batch for writing in the doc here is my code for updation in the collection.

```
batch.set(
  rootCollections.x.doc(getISO8601Date())
    .collection(subCollection.y)
    .doc(change.after.get('Id')),
  {
    officeId: change.after.get('Id'),
    office: change.after.get('office'),
    status: change.after.get('status'),
    creationTimestamp:
      change.after.get('creationTimestamp') ||
      change.after.get('createTimestamp') ||
      change.after.get('timestamp'),
    activeUsers: [...new Set(phoneNumbers)].length,
    confirmedUers: activityCheckinSubscription.docs.length,
    uniqueActivities: [...new Set(activities)].length,
    payments: 0,
    contact: [
      `${change.after.data().creator.phoneNumber},${
        change.after.data().attachment['First Contact'].value
      }`,
    ],
  },
  { merge: true },
);
batch.set(
  rootCollections.x.doc(getISO8601Date()),
  {
    Added: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
  },
  { merge: true },
);
PromiseArray.push(batch.commit());
await Promise.all(PromiseArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are facing the same issue from this similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667469/firestore-document-too-much-contention-such-thing-in-realtime-database), where there were thousands of records in the database being updated. As clarified there, you have limitation of how much writes you can perform in a document in one second - more details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) - and even though Firestore sometimes might hang on with the faster writes, **it will fail at some point.**

As this is hard coded and a limit that it's imposed by Firestore, what you can try is the solution explained in this similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667469/firestore-document-too-much-contention-such-thing-in-realtime-database), that it's either change to Realtime Database, where the limit is not the number of writes, but the size of the data or in case of the usage of a counter or some other data aggregation in Firestore, to use a distributed counter solution, that you can get more details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).

To summarize, there isn't much you can do unless of workaround it with this solution, as this is a limitation documented of Firestore.